# Android studio string file(too long lines). Soft wraps were forcibly enabled to improve editor performance

Tags: java, android, xml, string, android-studio

I have 23 xml files in Android studio. And every xml file has Textview with text in values/string. `<string name="long_text1 to 23"`. 
If text has not a lot of characters it's okey, but when I paste a big amount of text it gives Gradle.build mistakes. How can I insert a big amount of text and what code should I write in java file?  Should I create a new string for every textView? Thank you.

```
    [https://i.stack.imgur.com/duI4a.png][1]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the first error, the rest is a consequence of the first so they can be ignored.

Without your exact string it's hard to tell what's going on, but based on the error message I guess the following: the long text that you pasted contains special characters that make AAPT blow up. It's complaining about "Multiple substitutions specified in non-positional format", which means you have multiple `%s`/`%d`/etc... this is not allowed in Android.

```
<!-- Correct non-positional with single string substitution -->
<string name="formatted_string">Hello %s!</string>
<!-- Correct non-positional with single string substitution -->
<string name="formatted_number">result=%d</string>
<!-- Incorrect non-positional with multiple substitutions -->
<string name="formatted_multi">Hello %s! The result is %d.</string>
<!-- Corrected non-positional to positional with multiple substitutions -->
<string name="formatted_multi_fixed">Hello %1$s! The result is %2$d.</string>
```

Read both chapters on "Argument Index" at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html

You can try something like:

```
<string name="random_string" formatted="false" translatable="false" xml:space="preserve"
        tools:ignore="TypographyQuotes,TypographyDashes,TypographyEllipsis,TypographyFractions,TypographyOther"><![CDATA["
    Long string with <anything> weird %in %it, "most" of what you put here shou'd be ok...
"]]></string>
```

but there's still a possibility that AAPT won't like it. If the string is complex I would suggest putting it into a file under `src/main/assets` or `src/main/res/raw` and using the appropriate API to load those.

Comment: Appreciated for your response I will try it.

Comment: Appologize, but it gives to me this:  AidlTokenType.import or AidiTokenType.package expected  .

Comment: I don't know what that means, I've never seen that. You need to learn to provide relevant information when you ask a question; that message may not be related to this issue at all, just the build went on to do the next thing and failed again. "It doesn't work" or "BUILD FAILED" or "NullPointerException" is not enough, you need to provide example code, and input so the reader sees what's going on. I suggest updating your question with more details, or ask another question.

Comment: Sorry . I'm still learning this website. Picture: http://i.stack.imgur.com/duI4a.png

Comment: Did you try wrapping in CDATA? (encoding looks ok, because you use UTF-8). Also make sure you're fixing the first error in the file first, because this may be valid Russian text, but something above is making it interpret strings as code or similar.

Comment: Appreciated a lot. Have a good day. Helped me a lot